# why alarmManager from Service causes IllegalStateException only in certain device?

Tags: android, kotlin

I use `ForegroundService` and in order to make keep working, I write code in `onStartCommand` and return `START_STICKY`.

In there I use `alarmManager`, so I register alarmManger there.

```
// 알람 매니저
    val alarmManager =
        applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val alarmBroadcastReceiver = AlarmBroadcastReceiver()
    registerReceiver(alarmBroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(ALARM_NOTIFICATION_NAME))

    val alarmIntent = Intent(applicationContext, AlarmBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        applicationContext,
        ALARM_REQ_CODE,
        alarmIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )

    val newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }

    alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        newCalendar.timeInMillis,
        pendingIntent
    )
```

I need to user alarm even on doze/standby mode of device, I use `setAndAllowWhileIdle`, not `setInexactRepeating().

But `setAndAllowWhileIdle` is not repeated, so when It registered and call broadcast receiver, I link another local broadcast receiver from there.

It sends to local broadcast receiver (let's say broadcast receiver B) that alarm broadcast receiver (let's say broadcast receiver A) is called,

And in local broadcast receiver B, I register new alarm Manager to be called after 30 minutes from that time to make repeating alarm.

```
  var BroadcastReregister: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

            val alarmManager =
                applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            val alarmBroadcastReceiver = AlarmBroadcastReceiver()
            registerReceiver(alarmBroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(ALARM_NOTIFICATION_NAME))
            val alarmIntent = Intent(applicationContext, AlarmBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                applicationContext,
                ALARM_REQ_CODE,
                alarmIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )

            if (intent!!.action == "ALARM_BROADCAST_RECEIVER_RING") {

                if (alarmBroadcastReceiverCalled) {

                    val newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                        timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    }
                    newCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30)
                    
                    alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(
                        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        newCalendar.timeInMillis,
                        pendingIntent
                    )
...
```

It works perfect in 7 devices among 8 devices.

But in one device I get error message below:

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException:
  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull (Parcel.java:3031)
  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:3007)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2990)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2932)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiverWithFeature (IActivityManager.java:5916)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal (ContextImpl.java:1879)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver (ContextImpl.java:1813)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver (ContextImpl.java:1801)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver (ContextWrapper.java:764)
  at com.chugnchunon.chungchunon_android.Service.MyService$BroadcastReregister$1.onReceive (MyService.kt:597)
  at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts (LocalBroadcastManager.java:313)
  at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage (LocalBroadcastManager.java:121)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8757)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:571)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1067)
Caused by android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.registerReceiverWithFeature (ActivityManagerService.java:15660)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact (IActivityManager.java:2638)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact (ActivityManagerService.java:3118)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal (Binder.java:1316)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransact (Binder.java:1280)
```

As it says, `MyService.kt:597` line points below line that new alarm that will be called after 30m is registered in local broadcast receiver B.

```
 registerReceiver(alarmBroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(ALARM_NOTIFICATION_NAME))
```

I guess, it happens because this app already registered alarm of `ALARM_REQ_CODE`, but I registered new alarm of same code.

My guess is correct? But why don't other 7 devices meet this issue with same code?

And if my guess is true, can I solve the problem with the way that I make alarmManager and pending intent as `global` val and registered again with new Calendar..?